vscode wont launch on macos
Yes, I know there are a lot of questions on this topic but I have tried everything but VSCode still doesn't open in macOS.
I am using VSCode version - 1.91.0 (x64)
This is what code --verbose prints out:
[File Watcher (node.js)] Request to start watching: /Users/nikhildoshi/Library/Application Support/Code/User (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, filter: <none>, correlationId: <none>),/Users/nikhildoshi/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, filter: <none>, correlationId: <none>)
[3653:0708/005927.749646:ERROR:node_bindings.cc(162)] Fatal error in V8: v8::Template::Set Invalid value, must be a primitive or a Template
[0708/005927.763250:WARNING:process_memory_mac.cc(94)] mach_vm_read(0x7ffeec6c3000, 0x2000): (os/kern) invalid address (1)
[0708/005928.031383:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(43)] opendir /Users/nikhildoshi/Library/Application Support/Code/Crashpad/attachments/35b2025f-121c-4827-a72d-f7ba355e1422: No such file or directory (2)
[0708/005928.081788:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(235)] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)


I have also tried deleting and reinstalling vscode
Rebooting my laptop multiple times
Tried ps aux | grep Code.app to kill any running instances of vscode.


Try deleting that directory mentioned in the first line too. Could be a bad data file, or plugin too (if this used to work and then stopped).

The issue is not with the project since it used to open before, also I tried opening other projects as well but the issue is that VSCode itself won't launch

I meant the folder listed below, from your error message. This is part of VS Code’s data, not your project.
/Users/nikhildoshi/Library/Application Support/Code/User

Ohh okay, I see, but is it safe to delete the entire User folder? because there are many setting and json and xml, and etc files in those folders

Then rename to folder or move it to your desktop. If the app does work after that, you can quit, move a file back, try the app, and repeat until you find the offending file. But, removing local data like this is like getting a fresh install of the app. Look for other VSCode folders/files too. Or create a new acct on your Mac and try the app there, which will also be like a fresh install.
